# Virtual host redirecting to localhost

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I've tried to add a virtual host in my `localserver@apache@xampp/lampp@ubuntu@linux`

I've the following configuration in my http-vhosts.conf

**#Without any comments**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost mysite:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite/"

  <Directory "/var/www/mysite/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've the following in my `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.2   mysite

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The problem I got is that, when I navigate to `http://mysite/`, I get redirected to `http://localhost/`. And I've checked, no `.htaccess` file is redirecting to `http://localhost/`

## Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: did you solve this yet?